# Mock a api response

Tags: python, pytest

**Background**

I have a function called submit_health which is responsible for doing a POST request on some data we pass. The expected output is always in the following form :

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": [],
    "success": true
}
```

The only difference is that in some cases if we send invalid data the `"success": false` is possible and of course "errors" and "warnings" would have the appropriate text stating why there was no successful post request.

**Code**

```
   def submit_health(health_data):
        return _post_json("health-single", health_data)


def _post_json(resource: str, data: Dict) -> PostResponse:
    json_data = json.dumps(data, default=json_encoding_decimal_default)
    response = request_session_with_retry().post(
        f"{SITE_API_ROOT}/v3/{resource}",
        auth=("", SITE_API_V3_KEY),
        data=json_data,
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "User-Agent": USER_AGENT},
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
    try:
        return json.loads(response.text)
    except Exception:
        return None
```

**ISSUE**

I am attempting to test the `submit_health` function using pytest. I am not concerned with the implementation of the API as a different part of the code is dealing with that test. I am only concerned with testing it with the expected output which is

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": [],
    "success": true
}
```

My question is how would I mock this response? I would love for any suggestions. I read a little bit about monkey patching but I am not quite sure yet how to mock a response. I would love for some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your function is located in `health.py` module I would create a `test_health.py` module with code:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from health import submit_health


@patch("health.request_session_with_retry")
def test_submit_health(request_mock):
    response_mock = Mock(text='{"errors": [], "warnings": [], "success": true}')
    request_mock.return_value.get.return_value = response_mock

    result = submit_health({"foo": "bar"})

    assert result == {"errors": [], "warnings": [], "success": True}
```

1. `@patch` passes the patched function as an argument which I named `request_mock`
2. We need to mas what that mock is going to return when `request_session_with_retry.get` is called

Comment: @bigbounty any reason you recommend context managers?